# Logstash - sleep until there is a specific message

Tags: logstash, sleep

In Logstash, let's say I have the following lines in my logs:

```
Message: msisdn: 111111111
Message: msisdn: 222222222
Answer: msisdn: 111111111
Answer: msisdn: 222222222
```

Now, whenever I get the **Message**, I'd like to wait for X seconds.
If within this time period I get the matching **Answer** (i.e. with the same msisdn), mark it as **OK**, else mark it as **ERROR**.

How can I do that?

Thanks

```
**EDIT**
```

Fairy, I tried to work with the aggregate filter but with no success, can you please help me with that?

```
input {
  stdin {}
}

filter {
  grok {
    match => {"message" => "%{GREEDYDATA:type}: msisdn: %{INT:msisdn}"}
  }

  if [type] == "Message" {
    aggregate {
      task_id => "%{msisdn}"
      code => "event.set('result', 'OK')"
      timeout => 5
      timeout_code => "event.set('result', 'error')"
    }
  }

  if [logger] == "Answer" {
    aggregate {
      task_id => "%{msisdn}"
      code => "event.set('result', 'OK')"
      end_of_task => true
    }
  }

  if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] {
    drop {}
  }

}

output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

After writing this line to the stdin:

```
Message: msisdn: 111111111
```

There was a response immediately (it didn't wait 5 seconds) with status OK

```
{
    "result" => "OK",
    "@timestamp" => 2017-03-30T17:58:39.940Z,
    "@version" => "1",
    "host" => "31634cf481d5",
    "message" => "Message: msisdn: 111111111",
    "type" => "Message",
    "msisdn" => "111111111"
}
```

Should I write it differently?

Many thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `aggregate` filter pretty much does what you are describing. First you need to identify the `task_id` to which you correlate your messages. Then you set up your logstash filter so it get the type of the message and your `task_id`. Then we have to seperate `aggregate` filters, one for the first theother for the second event.

The first has the timeout and the code to set the event to error should it timeout. The second filter checks for the Answer message and ends the aggregation.

```
grok {
  match => {%{DATA:type}: %{DATA:name}: %{DATA:id}}
}

if [type] == "Message" {
  aggregate {
    task_id => "%{id}"
    code => "event.set('result', 'OK')"
    timeout => 5
    timeout_code => "event.set('result', 'error')"
  }
}

if [type] == "Answer" {
  aggregate {
    task_id => "%{id}"
    code => "event.set('result', 'OK')"
    end_of_task => true
  }
}
```

Check out the documentation for the `aggregate` filter [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-aggregate.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was very helpful

Comment: Hi, I tried that but with no success, can you please take a look (I edited the original message).